# How to swap round every nth column and format the contents in R?

Tags: r

So I have this:

```
# Open CSV files
df <- read.csv2("file1.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ":", dec = "-")

# Delete the first column
df <- df[-1]

# Delete every 3rd and 4th columns
i1 <- rep(seq(3, ncol(df), 4) , each = 2) + 0:1
df <- df[,-i1]

# Remove field names
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = ",title", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = ",url", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)

write.table(df[], "result.lua", quote=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)

# Done
cat("\nDONE.  Output written to result.txt.\n")
```

This is the file that is being read (file1.txt):

```
{"id":53203,"title":"bbc-moment","url":"https:wow.bbc.com\/bbc-ids\/live\/enus\/211\/53203","type":"audio\/mpeg"},{"id":53204,"title":"shg-moment","url":"https:\/\/wow.shg.com\/shg-ids\/live\/enus\/212\/53204","type":"audio\/mpeg"},{"id":53205,"title":"was-zone","url":"https:\/\/wow.was.com\/was-ids\/live\/enus\/213\/53205","type":"audio\/mpeg"},{"id":53206,"title":"xx1-zone","url":"https:\/\/wow.xx1.com\/xx1-ids\/live\/enus\/214\/53206","type":"audio\/mpeg"}
```

And this is the output file (result.txt):

```
"53203" "bbc-moment" "53204" "shg-moment" "53205" "was-zone" "53206" "xx1-zone"
```

So the script is working, it's outputting the correct fields in the correct order.  But I would like the output in result.txt to be like this:

```
"bbc-moment#53203",
"shg-moment#53204",
"was-zone#53205",
"xx1-zone#53206",
```

(with the quotes and comma symbols as shown).

How can I add to my code to achieve that in R?

Edit:

Adding this works for column 1 and 2.  But I need to do this recursively so it works for columns 1 & 2, 3 & 4, 5 & 6, etc.

```
df <- data.frame(new_col = paste('"', df$V3, '#', df$V2, '",', sep = ""))
```

Thank you.

Edit 2:

The exact contents of file.txt is:

```
{"id":53201,"title":"m1","url":"x1","type":"5"}{"id":53227,"title":"m2","url":"x2","type":"5"},{"id":53301,"title":"m3","url":"x3","type":"5"}
```

Edit 3:

I got it working with the marked answer below but with this change:

```
df <- data.frame(new_col = paste0('"', df[seq(2, ncol(df), 2)], '#', df[seq(1, ncol(df)-1, 2)], '"', ','))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `seq()` to select odd or even elements from your output file (result.txt) and paste them together into a new column

```r
# your current result.txt file
x <- c("53203", "bbc-moment", "53204", "shg-moment", "53205", "was-zone", "53206", "xx1-zone")

# new format
df <- data.frame(new_col = paste0('"', x[seq(2,8,2)], '#', x[seq(1,7,2)], '"', ','))

# output file
write.table(df, "result_v2.txt", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

When you check your new output file (result_v2.txt), you will have:

```
"bbc-moment#53203",
"shg-moment#53204",
"was-zone#53205",
"xx1-zone#53206",
```

Comment: Actually there is a problem, this code doesnt work on my file.  Do you know what the problem is?  I'll add the exact contents of file1.txt to my original question.

Comment: I added the exact contents of file1.txt as 'Edit 2' in my original question.  So when I use your code on that file, it shows an error 'Error in `[.data.frame`(df, seq(2, 8, 2)) : undefined columns selected'

Comment: I figured out the issue.  It seems there needs to be at least 4 tables in file1.txt (each one inside braces) and there can't a comma between them.  So still needs a bit of work.

Comment: This solution seemed great but it only works if there are 4 tables in file1.txt.  When there are less than 4, it shows an error.  When there are more than 4, it doesn't show any error but there are only 4 results in result.txt.  How can it be made to work for any number of tables in file1.txt?

Comment: I got it to work with any number of tables by changing your code to this df <- data.frame(new_col = paste0('"', df[seq(2, ncol(df), 2)], '#', df[seq(1, ncol(df)-1, 2)], '"', ',')), i will update my question with the working code but mark your answer as correct

Comment: @Jstation - Yeah, the second parameter in `seq()` indicates where to end the sequence count. I used 8 and 7 because your original example had elements up to that amount. Certainly changing them to `ncol(df)` and `ncol(df)-1`, respectively, will be more universal--though a pre-existing `df` must be present (it wasn't the case in my solution as I didn't define it in my solution). Run `?seq` to see more info on the `seq()` function.